# Attached device doesn't appear in AVD manager (linux)

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, debugging

My device appears attached from ./adb devices but non in AVD Manager. lsusb result is positive and I also tried ./adb kill-server after that ./adb start-server

I've followed the android's official guide but still no positive response. Does it matter if my device is a tablet?

Comment: Have you set USB Debug on your device? Do you have this line in your manifest (remove it or set it "true") android:debuggable="false"?

Comment: My device is on usb debug mode. My manifest has android:debuggable="true"

Comment: Then I think that **Sanket990** answer is your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to a "real" device attached to your computer, why would it appear in android "virtual" device manager?
AVD manager lists only virtual devices running on an emulator.
If your real device is connected with USB debugging enabled and and it appears in ADB connected devices, you are good to go.

Comment: You are right... I have only select MainActivity.java tab and after that press RUN. Choose a Android running device and presso ok. Thank you

Comment: sorry low reputation .(

Comment: You cant up vote but you can accept answer, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

AVD will list only virtual devices

enable usb debugging and use the monitor tool under sdk/tools dir 
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html

Answer (score 0):

If your using linux then require your android device entry in **51-android.rules** files
plz check the
 Setting up a Device for Development in below link

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

your device add in 51-android.rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

after adb kill-server and adb start-server apply that's working